# Prefix is not added to table on artisan migrate

Tags: laravel, database-migration, prefix

I ran `php artisan migrate`, with empty value for prefix in the database config file.

Later I added a value for prefix in the database config file.

And then when I run `php artisan migrate:refresh`, the prefix is not added to the table. Why is that and what am I missing ?

This is my database config after adding prefix

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'database'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'laravel'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'laravel'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => 'my_prefix_',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
]
```

Comment: Try `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: Currently the `prefix` option is bugged for indexes and foreign keys and will not be fixed until at least v5.6. Thus, I would suggest avoiding to use it for now. Source:https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be cache problem. Laravel can remember old settigns.

Run artisan command and try again:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try below command and check:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Note: You changed `config` folder files so you need to clear config cache.

Comment: This command: php artisan config:cache include php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

Prefix should be specified in the migration class inorder to add prefix to tables